# Why is dateFormat causing an "Uncaught ReferenceError: dateFormat is not defined" error?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a site I didn't build and one page keeps giving an error in the console of "Uncaught ReferenceError:  dateFormat is not defined"

Below is the JS that contains the error (at line 7).  Why would that show as not defined?  Is it not a standard function in JS?  Does there need to be a line before it that declares it, something like "var dateFormat = (something)"?  Just curious if anyone knows offhand. Otherwise, I'll keep googling...

```
MktoForms2.whenReady(function(form) {

    var formElem=form.getFormElem();

    var systemDateVal = '{{system.date}}';
    if (systemDateVal.indexOf('{{system') !== -1) {
        systemDateVal = dateFormat("mediumDate");
    }

    function delete_cookie(name, path, domain) {
        document.cookie = name + "=" + ((path) ? ";path=" + path : "") + ((domain) ? ";domain=" + domain : "") + "; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
    }

    $("#resetForm").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(formElem).trigger('reset');
        delete_cookie('_mkto_trk', '/', '.spirent.com');
    });

        var optinsDateFields = {
            'Opt_in_Corp_Info__c': ['Marketing_Email_Opt_in_Date__c', 'marketingEmailOptoutDate']
        }

        var changeOptinAction = function(event) {
            var optinname = $(event.target).attr('name');
            if (optinsDateFields.hasOwnProperty(optinname)) {
                if ($(event.target).is(':checked')) {
                    $('[name=' + optinsDateFields[optinname][0] + ']', formElem).val(systemDateVal);
                    $('[name=' + optinsDateFields[optinname][1] + ']', formElem).val('');
                } else {
                    $('[name=' + optinsDateFields[optinname][1] + ']', formElem).val(systemDateVal);
                    $('[name=' + optinsDateFields[optinname][0] + ']', formElem).val('');
                }
            }
        }

        $('[name="Opt_in_Corp_Info__c"]', formElem).on('change', function (e) {
            changeOptinAction(e);
        });
        $('[name="Opt_in_Corp_Info__c"]', formElem).change();
});
```

Comment: *Is it not a standard function in JS?* - Nope, it would need to be implemented yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is either a function defined locally for your code or it is from the dateform npm module.

Installation is npm install dateformat and to initialize it you need

var dateFormat = require('dateformat');

mediumDate is a named format for this module as can be seen here. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat
and has the following format Jun 9, 2007

Comment: I added the initialize line and then it gave "require is not defined."  So I'm thinking maybe it's not using NPM.